# SteamAPI, не работает метод GetOwnedGames

Tags: json, steam-web-api

Приветствую.
Может кто знает, почему не работает метод GetOwnedGames в SteamAPI ?
Отправляю такой запрос:
`https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key=KEY&steamid=STEAM_ID` , где `KEY` и `STEAM_ID` - настоящие рабочие параметры.
Проверял их на методах GetSteamLevel и GetBadges.

Также добавлял параметры: `&include_appinfo=1` и `&include_played_free_games=1` - ничего не меняется. И добавлял `&appids_filter` - параметр (uint32), не смотря на то, что он должен содержать целочисленное положительное значение и не более 32 символов, я пихал туда 200 разных символов, и не получил даже ошибку. Еще непонятно, почему все поля - Required, судя по [документации](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/IPlayerService#GetOwnedGames).

А ответ всегда такой:

```
{
    "response": {

    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите пример итогового url (без key, разумеется). Вероятно, steamid не тот передаёте.

Comment: Ключ какой используете? web api key? или ключ паблишера?

Comment: GET https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&format=xml&steamid=YYYYYYYYYYYYY

Comment: Web api key я взял с https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey

Comment: Пример steamId дайте.

Comment: О боже, Вы правы. Я неправильно указал steamid. В итоге сгенерил мне ИД вот этот сервис https://steamdb.info/calculator/.

Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Рад был помочь ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Неверно указан steamId. Вы можете его посмотреть в сорсах страницы профиля.

К примеру, для [моего](http://steamcommunity.com/id/suvitruf/) профиля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или же воспользоваться сервисом вроде [steamdb](https://steamdb.info/calculator/).